# strang result from django annotate or django dublicate the resulte

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have this code

```
    centers = Center.objects.filter(branch=request.user.center.branch,name="test").annotate(
transaction_out=Coalesce(Sum('_TransactionOut__amount', filter=Q(_TransactionOut__date_time__gte=thirty_days_ago)),Value(0.0)),

)
```

the result of transactio_out is 2000 which is correct

but if i add a new field to annotate called transaction in

```
    transaction_in=Coalesce(Sum('_TransactionIn__amount', filter=Q(_TransactionIn__date_time__gte=thirty_days_ago)),Value(0.0)),
```

it dublicate the reselut

for example

```
2000 --> 4000
5000 --> 10,000
```

full code :

```
 centers = Center.objects.filter(branch=request.user.center.branch,name="test").annotate(
    transaction_in=Coalesce(Sum('_TransactionIn__amount', filter=Q(_TransactionIn__date_time__gte=thirty_days_ago)),Value(0.0)),
    transaction_out=Coalesce(Sum('_TransactionOut__amount', filter=Q(_TransactionOut__date_time__gte=thirty_days_ago)),Value(0.0)),

    ) 

class TransactionIn(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    center=models.ForeignKey("center.Center",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True, related_name="_TransactionIn")
    
   
    
class TransactionOut(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField()
    user=models.ForeignKey("account.User",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)# related name
    center=models.ForeignKey("center.Center",on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True, related_name="_TransactionOut")



class Center(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
```

database query :

```
    SELECT "center_center"."id",
       "center_center"."name",
       "center_center"."branch_id",
       "center_center"."image",
       "center_center"."manager_id",
       "center_center"."lat",
       "center_center"."long",
       "center_center"."mobile_number",
       COALESCE(SUM("accounting_transactionin"."amount") FILTER (WHERE "accounting_transactionin"."date_time" >= '2023-06-10T21:08:09.278740+00:00'::timestamptz), 0.0) AS "transaction_in",
       COALESCE(SUM("accounting_transactionout"."amount") FILTER (WHERE "accounting_transactionout"."date_time" >= '2023-06-10T21:08:09.278740+00:00'::timestamptz), 0.0) AS "transaction_out"
  FROM "center_center"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounting_transactionin"
    ON ("center_center"."id" = "accounting_transactionin"."center_id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounting_transactionout"
    ON ("center_center"."id" = "accounting_transactionout"."center_id")
 WHERE ("center_center"."branch_id" = 1 AND "center_center"."name" = 'test')
 GROUP BY "center_center"."id"
```

Comment: It makes two left outer joins, hence the two act as a multiplier of each other.

Comment: yes it make tow left outer join , but how to solve that

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounting_transactionin"
    ON ("center_center"."id" = "accounting_transactionin"."center_id")
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounting_transactionout"
    ON ("center_center"."id" = "accounting_transactionout"."center_id")

I think not because everyone is at different tables.